# Creating table for each user?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm programming a web application in which each user stores their tasks. (like a to-do application). Tasks will be stored in a table (for example: *userstasks*).

Which one is better?

1- *userstasks* table has a column named user_id that defines who created task?

2- a new table (e.g. *usernametasks*) will be created for each registered user that stores all their tasks?

P.S.: There are lots of users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **always** start with the simplest thing that works and stick with it until it's *proven* to be a performance problem. What you're talking about with #2 is termed "premature optimization". You only go down that road when #1 is having severe performance problems.

When you split data across different users, your ability to query across all users is severely diminished. For all intents, users will be living in different worlds. Reporting is nearly impossible.

For most applications that have a lot of reads, millions of records is not an issue. It's write-heavy applications that need special attention like this, or those with massive scale, like Reddit or Twitter. Since you're not making one of those, stick with the properly normalized structure first.

"Lots of users" probably means tens or hundreds of thousands. On a properly tuned MySQL instance that's not a big deal. If you need more scale, spin up some read-only secondary servers to spread out the load or look at using MySQL cluster.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with option 1 (a table called tasks with a user_id foreign key) in the short run, assuming that a task can't have more than one user? If so then you'll need a JOIN table. Check into setting up an actual foreign key as well, this promotes referential integrity in the data itself.

Comment: Re. 'lots of users' unless you're well into the millions, it doesn't matter with any of the many production databases available. That said you should read up on how to properly index your tables.